# Apache Camel Error Handling With File Endpoints

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have a query around handling errors with File Endpoints

I have a scenario where I need to pull a file from an Endpoint, do some processing and then put the result of that processing onto a queue.

If the processing throws an error, I want the original to be placed into a configurable error directory.

If the processing succeeds, then I want the result to be placed onto a queue. If this fails then I want the original file to be placed in a different directory.

Is this even possible? ... My onException seems to be ignoring the file endpoint I have configured for it to be sent to

Comment: Can you show what you did ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes just configure the file endpoint with the following options

- `move` -> to move the file after it was processed successfully
- `moveFailed` -> to move a failed file to a error directory

See the file component for more details

- http://camel.apache.org/file2